# alias not working in terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

I'm on a mac in Terminal.

```
open -a "Sublime Text 2"
```

opens Sublmine Text 2, just like I want it to.

I now want to alias this to my .bashrc file, which I have an use for other things like prompt configuration.

```
alias sublime='open -a Submlime Text 2'
```

doesn't work. Neither does

```
alias sublime='open -a "Submlime Text 2"'
```

running

```
source ./.bashrc
```

doesn't help.
Each time I am told

```
/Volumes/Belladonna/Blake
≈:≈ sublime 
Unable to find application named 'Submlime Text 2'
```

I'm doing this wrong and I know it must be a simple answer...

Comment: You've misspelled Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1):

Either of these should work:

```
alias sublime='open -a "Sublime Text 2"'
alias sublime='open -a Sublime\ Text\ 2'
```

Comment: Backslashes will not work here, as you are already escaping the spaces with `'`.

Comment: @DisplayName, actually it will :)

Comment: No. It will look for an application that is called literally `Sublime\ Text\ 2`.

Comment: @DisplayName, you could try it in a bash shell yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I thought there was a ' before the S.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow Sublime Text's recommended procedure of creating a symbolic link to their command line tool you will be able to open files, use as an `$EDITOR` with git, subversion, etc… It gives much more power and flexibility over creating an alias.

In a nutshell you can use this command to create an symbolic link to the tool:

`ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl`

and then use the tool from the command line.

`subl --new-window ~/.profile`

will open your bash profile in a new window in "Sublime Text 2". You can also use the `subl` command without any arguments to open the app.

To get this to work you may need to add ~/bin to your `$PATH` variable in your ~/.profile.

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`

See also [Sublime Text's instructions](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).